# SQL Server: update multiple rows with one statement with calculation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I don't know is this possible in one SQL statement to update the refundamt?

I have these three rows initially, using insert statement:

```
NO  |  TRANAMT  |  REFUNDAMT
1   |  100      |  0 
2   |  200      |  0
3   |  300      |  0
```

If refund is 350, the refundamt will be updated as follow, the refundamt cannot be more then the tranamt:

```
NO  |  TRANAMT  |  REFUNDAMT
1   |  100      |  100 
2   |  200      |  200
3   |  300      |  50
```

When refund again with 50, the refundamt will be updated as follow

```
NO  |  TRANAMT  |  REFUNDAMT
1   |  100      |  100 
2   |  200      |  200
3   |  300      |  100
```

I think this is impossible to update refundamt using one sql statement. How about multiple satement? Not hoping to use store procedure. Can I use **select update**?

Comment: Not clear - can you explain better **how** you get from the first state to the second and then to the third?? What do you mean by *if refund is 350* - **what** refund? What column?? I see no refund at all in the first state.... And how do you get from the second to the third state?? What refund of 50 do you mean? Why is it only applied to the third row?? What are the **rules** ??

Comment: When you say "one" statement - what are you asking.  This would be a trivial stored procedure with a declared variable to keep track of refund amount and a while loop to apply row by row until the refund is all used up.  But does that meet your expectation of a single statement?  To me anything that runs in a single "batch" is a statement.

Comment: Are your refund amounts spread across each transaction. By this i mean it takes the 350 then starts at TRANAMT No1, takes off 100, then moves to No2, takes of 200, then moves down to No3 to take of the last 50.

Comment: Triggers are the solution to your problem you can use triggers. trigger will be fired based on condition updating the refundamt when it is 350 and again it will fire when your refundamt is 50 you can handle it by using if and else in trigger

Comment: Hoping not to use trigger or store procedure. How about looping the records, and update the refundamt. How can I do the calculation effectively.

Answer (score 2):

I think this works. It's a single statement. Not the prettiest. And I'd imagine the real Transactions table has more columns (e.g. an account number):

```
declare @RefundAmt int
set @RefundAmt = 350

; with Refunds as (
    select
        top 1
        NO,
        TRANAMT,
        CASE WHEN TRANAMT-REFUNDAMT < @RefundAmt THEN TRANAMT ELSE REFUNDAMT + @RefundAmt END as REFUNDAMT,
        CASE WHEN TRANAMT-REFUNDAMT < @RefundAmt THEN @RefundAmt - (TRANAMT-REFUNDAMT) ELSE 0 END as Remaining
    from
        dbo.Transactions
    where REFUNDAMT < TRANAMT ORDER BY NO
    union all
    select
        t2.NO,
        t2.TRANAMT,
        CASE WHEN t2.TRANAMT-t2.REFUNDAMT < t1.Remaining THEN t2.TRANAMT ELSE t2.REFUNDAMT + t1.Remaining END as REFUNDAMT,
        CASE WHEN t2.TRANAMT-t2.REFUNDAMT < t1.Remaining THEN t1.Remaining - (t2.TRANAMT-t2.REFUNDAMT) ELSE 0 END as Remaining
    from
        Refunds t1
            inner join
        dbo.Transactions t2
            on
                t1.NO = t2.NO - 1 and
                t1.Remaining > 0
)
update t set REFUNDAMT = r.REFUNDAMT
from
    dbo.Transactions t
        inner join
    Refunds r
        on
            t.NO = r.NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like...:  (needs work, but gives a conceptual idea)

```
Declare @pRefund Money
SET @pRefund = 350

WHILE @pRefund > 0
BEGIN
   /** SELECT Transaction Amount of min primary key where recorded refundamt is less than tranamt
   Apply matching refund
   Reduce @pRefund by amount applied
   If @pRefund is now less then next highest TransAMT Then apply whats left otherwise loop again
   refund has now been all applied and loop will exit */
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit messy, but here's what I came up with:

Code to set up your base tables...

```
-- setup code
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    [NO] int identity(1,1),
    [TRAN] money,
    [REFUND] money
)
INSERT #tmp VALUES (100, 0)
INSERT #tmp VALUES (200, 0)
INSERT #tmp VALUES (300, 0)
```

Code to add your refund amount...

```
DECLARE @amt money SET @amt = 50
UPDATE u 
SET REFUND =
    CASE    WHEN u.[REFUND] = u.[TRAN] THEN u.[REFUND] --'already full - do nothing'
        WHEN cumulativepretran >= aiming_for_ref THEN u.[REFUND] --'after all - do nothing'
        WHEN cumulativetran + cumulativeref > ((totalref + @amt) - u.[TRAN])  THEN  (totalref + @amt + u.[REFUND]) - (cumulativeref) --'calc'
        ELSE u.[TRAN] END -- 'fill-er-up'
FROM #tmp u
INNER JOIN (SELECT  *, 
    ISNULL((select sum([REFUND]) FROM #tmp WHERE [NO] <= t.[NO]), 0) 'cumulativeref',
    ISNULL((select sum([TRAN]) FROM #tmp WHERE [NO] <= t.[NO]), 0) 'cumulativetran',
    ISNULL((select sum([REFUND]) FROM #tmp WHERE [NO] < t.[NO]), 0) 'cumulativepreref',
    ISNULL((select sum([TRAN]) FROM #tmp WHERE [NO] < t.[NO]), 0) 'cumulativepretran',
    ISNULL((select sum([REFUND]) FROM #tmp), 0) 'totalref',
    ISNULL((select sum([REFUND]) FROM #tmp), 0) + @amt 'aiming_for_ref'
FROM #tmp t) as m ON m.[NO] = u.[NO]
```